# How to write recursion on loop properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion

I have such `List<IRequest>`

```
public interface IRequest
    {
        List<IRequest> Childrens { get; set; }
        bool RequestIsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

How to find `RequestIsSelected` object?

Let's say I have such structure

```
IRequest -
          |
          IRequest - 
                    |
                     IRequest  <--- if this one is true I can catch it
          |
          IRequest -
                    |
                     IRequest   <----- This one RequestIsSelected == true;  (I can't catch it)
```

I wrote such method

```
private IRequest GetSelectedItem(List<IRequest> entireList)
        {
            foreach(var tmp in entireList)
            {
                if(tmp.RequestIsSelected)
                {
                    return tmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    return GetSelectedItem(tmp.Childrens);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

But it iterates only on first deep line, if my selected item resides in second line my method returns null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] and tag a language ([tag:c#]?)

Comment: In the `else`, only `return` if the result of the recursive call is not `null`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what do you mean about your second comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `else`, only return if the result of the recursive call is not `null` since not finding it in the current child does not necessarily mean it is not in some other child list.

```
private IRequest GetSelectedItem(List<IRequest> entireList)
{
    if (entireList == null) return null;

    foreach(var tmp in entireList)
    {
        if(tmp.RequestIsSelected)
        {
            return tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            IRequest child = GetSelectedItem(tmp.Childrens);
            if (child != null) return child; 
            // Else keep searching since it may
            // be in some other child list
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```